# How to access array of strings in firestore and query on them

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a angular project with firestore as database.In database i stored a document with name uid which is an array of uids.How do I query on them.I searched a lot but all the suggestions are with firebase and not with firestore.

Comment: *How do I query on them* Its a weird question.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 29. May 2019**

You can now do this. There is an array_contains query:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains
You can use the array_contains operator to filter based on array values. For example:

```
citiesRef.where("regions", "array-contains", "west_coast")
```

regions is an array of strings and the above query will return only the documents that have "west_cost" in the array.

====================

**Old answer:**

Unfortunately you can't. from the docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, it does not support
>   querying array members or updating single array elements. However, you
>   can still model this kind of data by leveraging the other capabilities
>   of Cloud Firestore.

You can try making a map of values as suggested in the docs. This works in most cases unless you store more than 10k user uids on a single document, than you would run in some of the limitation of firestore.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

> Maximum number of index entries for each document
>
> 20,000
>
> The number of index entries is the sum of the following for a
>   document:
>
> ```
> The number of single-field index entries
> The number of composite index entries
> ```
>
> Cloud Firestore automatically creates two single-field index entries
>   for each field, one in the ascending index and one in the descending
>   index.
>
> Considering the limit of 20,000, each document can index a maximum of
>   10,000 fields minus the document's number of composite index entries.